# Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS: Can't set wallpaper

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-background

After having upgraded to Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS from 20.04 LTS, I noticed that my KDE desktop wallpaper doesn't display any more. Also, right clicking on the desktop, nothing happens, no menu is displayed. The only way I have to set a wallpaper is to use Dolphin and its "set as wallpaper" function. This works for the current session but the setting doesn't seem to be saved as, after rebooting, there is no wallpaper.
Wat am I missing here ?
Many thanks in advance.
Kind regards,
Nicolas